# Laravel 4 - The requested resource /painel was not found on this server

Tags: php, laravel-4

I get the following error when type `localhost:8000/painel`:

> The requested resource /painel was not found on this server.

I get the same error on any other computer that I have. Below, follow the routes:

```
// ROTA DE POSTS
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'site\PostsController@index'));

// route to show the login form
Route::get('/{slug}', array('as' => 'post.show', 'uses' => 'site\PostsController@show'));
Route::get('painel', array('uses' => 'painel\PainelLoginController@showLogin'));
Route::post('painel', array('uses' => 'painel\PainelLoginController@authenticate'));
Route::get('logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'painel\PainelLoginController@doLogout'));

Route::get('/p/{slug}', array('as' => 'pagina.show', 'uses' => 'site\PaginasController@show'));

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'painel', 'before' => 'auth'), function () {

    // ROTA DE POSTS NO ADMIN
    Route::get('/posts', array('as' => 'painel.post.index', 'uses' => 'painel\PainelPostsController@index'));
    Route::post('/post/store/', 'painel\PainelPostsController@store');
    Route::post('/post/{slug}/update/', 'painel\PainelPostsController@update');
    Route::get('/post/novo/', array('as' => 'painel.post.novo', 'uses' => 'painel\PainelPostsController@create'));
    Route::get('/post/{slug}/editar/', 'painel\PainelPostsController@edit');
    Route::get('/post/{slug}/deletar/', 'painel\PainelPostsController@destroy');

    // ROTA DE PÁGINAS NO ADMIN
    Route::get('/paginas', array('as' => 'painel.pagina.index', 'uses' => 'painel\PainelPaginasController@index'));
    Route::post('/pagina/store/', 'painel\PainelPaginasController@store');
    Route::post('/pagina/{slug}/update/', 'painel\PainelPaginasController@update');
    Route::get('/pagina/novo/', array('as' => 'painel.pagina.novo', 'uses' => 'painel\PainelPaginasController@create'));
    Route::get('/pagina/{slug}/editar/', array('as' => 'painel.pagina.edit', 'uses' => 'painel\PainelPaginasController@edit'));
    Route::get('/pagina/{slug}/deletar/', 'painel\PainelPaginasController@destroy');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
Route::get('painel', array('uses' => 'PainelLoginController@showLogin'));
```

without your directory `painel\` (i assume it's your directory). laravel automatically checks that class **PainelLoginController** and knows where it lies. this is done through the autoloader. you can have a peek under `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Put slashes before the route deceleration?

Route::get('/painel', array('uses' => 'painel\PainelLoginController@showLogin'));

Comment: Answer is assuming all you other routes work fine. If they don't, maybe try have a look at your .htaccess, and if you haven't replaced/modified (in a strange kind of way) the one that ships with Laravel.